# Python setup.cfg: how to add package_data with git submodules?

Tags: python, setuptools, git-submodules, python-packaging

I'm writing a Python package, in which I'm adding package data. The package data of my setup.cfg looks like the following:

```
include_package_data = True
[options.package_data]
mypymodule = dir1/*/*, dir2/*/*
```

Both dir1 and dir2 are directories inside mypymodule source folder, which is part of "mypackage". Building, installing and using "mypackage" is not an issue.

The trouble I'm facing is the following:

Both dir1 and dir2 have their subdirectories with some files inside each that I want to include in "mypackage" installation, and then access them as resources when "mypackage" is running.

For dir1, everything is fine: all dir1 subfolders are correctly installed within "mypackage".

But for dir2, it looks like the installation is not recursive: only files belonging directly at the dir2 folder are installed within "mypackage"; all dir2 subfolders are ignored in "mypackage" installation, and I am not able to access their content as resources.

The difference between dir1 and dir2 is:

- dir1 is a regular directory in "mypackage" git repo
- dir2 is added in "mypackage" git repo as a git submodule

What am I missing? Is there some limitations in adding git submodules are package_data in Python packages setup.cfg?

Hope you can help! Thank you!

I've tried changing the "*" notation for subdirectories in setup.cfg file, but with no success. I expect that both dir1 and dir2 are treated evenly whether regular dirs or git submodule dirs.

Comment: What if you remove `dir1` from the line? What if you put each on their own line?

Comment: Actually I have more items in the same line and it seems fine. Each item is like "dirname/*", but for dir1 and dir2 I need to include all subdirectories with all files inside them, hence the "dir/*/*" notation. Even for dir1, which I mentioned that it works, if I use just the "dir1/*" notation, the subdirectories are note included.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifications. I do not see the issue, it seems all fine to me. You could check again the documentation ([setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) and maybe even [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)), and you could also try the [`MANIFEST.in` method](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/). -- Are all the sub-directories also importable sub-packages (do they all contain a `__init__.py`)?

Comment: Both dir1 and dir2 directories contents are not Python modules; they are miscelaneous text files which I use as templates in my application.

Comment: Then, I would recommend you to read this again: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#subdirectory-for-data-files -- Maybe you need to make sure to use the `packages = find_namespace:`. -- Otherwise you need to provide a full [mre], because it is impossible for us to guess what your project really looks like.

Comment: I fount the solution for my problem. The problem is much simpler than I thought. I had not to do with one folder being a git repo or anything. It is a matter of the "/*/*" notation. For each subdir level I need to include, it is needed an extra "/*". In my application, for dir2 I had to include another one: dir2/*/*/*. Is there a way of including all sublevels at once? Something like -r parameters in some Linux commands, which considers all subdir structure.

Comment: Typically it is with double star `**`, but I do not know if it works in this case.

Comment: Double star did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the sub dir notation I used; there is nothing to with one of the dirs being a git repo or not. I just mistaken the sub dir level I wanted to include.

For including recursiely anything below a dir, double star notation `**` is needed. Backslashs plus stars `/*/*` only adds until the denoted level.

The correct notation in my example is:

```
include_package_data = True
[options.package_data]
mypymodule = dir1/**, dir2/**
```